# How to make Bitsy work in Glassfish with Jython from multiple Flask routes? (BitsyException: INSTANCE_ALREADY_EXISTS)

Tags: java, flask, glassfish-3, jython-2.7, bitsy

I am running into a snag with my code, and am hoping someone can help.

I have an application I am building, where I am being forced to use Java and deploy it to a Glassfish 3.1 server. This is not how I normally prefer to work, as I am more of a Python developer. As such, I have tied into using Jython 2.7, and am using Flask.

However, I am using the Bitsy implementation of the Blueprints graph DB API in order to construct a graph representing the data my application will serve in a REST-based API (derived from an Oracle DB, using JPA 2.0).

I have successfully been able to build my graph with the following code:

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function

import collections
import java.lang.Class
import java.lang.Runtime
import java.nio.file.Paths
import os
import tempfile

import concurrent.futures
from flask import Flask

import contextlib2 as contextlib
import javax.persistence.Persistence as JPA

import com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyGraph

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])

def process_indi(pool, graph, parent_key, indi_key):
    """
    Processes a single indicator to be loaded on the graph.
    """
    indi_class = java.lang.Class.forName("pampas.db.r.models.Indi")
    manager_factory = JPA.createEntityManagerFactory("pampas-r")
    manager = manager_factory.createEntityManager()
    try:
        indi = manager.createNamedQuery('Indi.findByIndiKey', indi_class)
        indi = indi.setParameter("indi_key", indi_key)
        indi = indi.singleResult
        trans = graph.newTransaction()
        try:
            vert = trans.addVertex(None)

            vert.setProperty('indi_key', indi.cidIndicatorKey)

            if indi_key == 'SYSTEM_ROOT':
                region_class = java.lang.Class.forName("pampas.db.r.models.Region")
                region = manager.createNamedQuery('Region.findThis', region_class)
                region = region.singleResult
                vert.setProperty('name', region.cidRegion)

                status_text_class = java.lang.Class.forName("pampas.db.r.models.StatusText")
                status_text = manager.createNamedQuery('StatusText.findAll', status_text_class)
                states = {
                    state.cidStatus: state.ctxDesc
                    for state in status_text.resultList
                }
                vert.setProperty('states', states)
            else:
                vert.setProperty('name', indi.ctxDesc)

                states = {
                    threshold.id.nnoStatus: threshold.ctxDesc
                    for threshold in indi.thresholds
                }
                if states:
                    vert.setProperty('states', states)

            if indi.ctxTooltip is not None:
                vert.setProperty('tooltip', indi.ctxTooltip)
            if indi.ctxHyperlink is not None:
                vert.setProperty('link', indi.ctxHyperlink)

            with contextlib.suppress(AttributeError):
                vert.setProperty('status', indi.script.statusText.cidStatus)
                vert.setProperty('last_updated', indi.script.dtCurrent)

            with contextlib.suppress(AttributeError):
                if indi.vSuppressActives.size() > 0:
                    for suppress in indi.vSuppressActives:
                        print(suppress.ctxComment)
                    vert.setProperty('suppressed', True)

            with contextlib.suppress(AttributeError):
                key_value = False
                edit_list = False
                for plugin_value in indi.pluginValues:
                    if plugin_value.pluginGroup.ctxEditType == 'KEY_VALUE':
                        key_value = True
                    elif plugin_value.pluginGroup.ctxEditType == 'LIST':
                        edit_list = True

                    if key_value and edit_list:
                        break

                if key_value:
                    vert.setProperty('key_value', key_value)
                if edit_list:
                    vert.setProperty('edit_list', edit_list)

            if parent_key is not None:
                parent = None
                for item in trans.getVertices('indi_key', indi.parent.cidIndicatorKey):
                    parent = item
                    break
                trans.addEdge(None, vert, parent, 'ancestor')
                print('{parent} => {child}'.format(
                    parent=parent.getProperty('name'), child=vert.getProperty('name')))
            else:
                print(vert.getProperty('name'))
        finally:
            trans.commit()

        futures = tuple(
            pool.submit(process_indi, pool, graph, vert, child.cidIndicatorKey)
            for child in indi.children
        )
    finally:
        manager.close()

    return futures


@app.route('/gen_tree')
def gen_tree():
    """
    Generate the tree and load it into the Bitsy (Blueprints) GraphDB.
    """
    db_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'pampas', 'graph')
    with contextlib.suppress(OSError):
        os.makedirs(db_path)
    db_path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(db_path)
    graph = com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyGraph(db_path)

    vertex_class = java.lang.Class.forName("com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex")
    try:
        trans = graph.newTransaction()
        try:
            trans.createKeyIndex('indi_key', vertex_class)
            trans.createKeyIndex('suppressed', vertex_class)
        finally:
            trans.commit()

        futures = collections.deque()
        runtime = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()
        cpu_count = runtime.availableProcessors()
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(cpu_count * 5) as pool:
            batch = process_indi(pool, graph, None, 'SYSTEM_ROOT')
            if batch:
                futures.append(batch)

            while futures:
                block = futures.popleft()
                for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(block):
                    batch = future.result()
                    if batch:
                        futures.append(batch)
                print('Num Vertices:', len(tuple(graph.getVertices())), '| Num Edges:', len(tuple(graph.getEdges())))

    finally:
        graph.shutdown()

    return 'Graph DB built.'
```

This works beautifully, and generates my graph exactly how I want it.

However, when I add the following:

```
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.wrappers.readonly.ReadOnlyGraph

@app.route('/')
def read_tree():
    db_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'pampas', 'graph')
    with contextlib.suppress(OSError):
        os.makedirs(db_path)
    db_path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(db_path)
    graph = com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyGraph(db_path)
    rograph = com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.wrappers.readonly.ReadOnlyGraph(graph)
    root = None
    for node in rograph.getVertices('indi_key', 'SYSTEM_ROOT'):
        root = node
        break
    return root.getProperty('name')
```

And I try to run this code (from http://localhost:8080/data/ based on other configurations), I get the following:

```
2016-08-31T11:02:06.745-0400|Info: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():debug: Attempting to import application callable 'wsgi.application'

2016-08-31T11:02:06.746-0400|Info: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():debug: Application is <Flask 'pampas'>
2016-08-31T11:02:06.862-0400|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[modjy]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet modjy threw exception
com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyException: INSTANCE_ALREADY_EXISTS: A BitsyGraph object with the same path has been registered with the MBeanServer. Creating multiple instances of BitsyGraph (without calling shutdown) will cause data corruption. Path C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pampas\graph
    at com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyGraph.<init>(BitsyGraph.java:91)
    at com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyGraph.<init>(BitsyGraph.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedConstructor.constructProxy(PyReflectedConstructor.java:211)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedConstructor.__call__(PyReflectedConstructor.java:180)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:419)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:237)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:228)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:223)
    at org.python.core.Deriveds.dispatch__init__(Deriveds.java:19)
    at org.python.core.PyObjectDerived.dispatch__init__(PyObjectDerived.java:1112)
    at org.python.core.PyType.type___call__(PyType.java:1713)
    at org.python.core.PyType.__call__(PyType.java:1696)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:461)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:465)
    at pampas.test$py.read_tree$1(C:\Users\QTB0065\Apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\pampas\applications\pampas-be\pampas\test.py:74)
    at pampas.test$py.call_function(C:\Users\QTB0065\Apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\pampas\applications\pampas-be\pampas\test.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:307)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.function___call__(PyFunction.java:471)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:466)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:461)
    at org.python.core.PyObject._callextra(PyObject.java:601)
    at flask.app$py.dispatch_request$69(C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bmhjzf\flask\flask\app.py:1625)
    at flask.app$py.call_function(C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bmhjzf\flask\flask\app.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:138)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:413)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:126)
    at flask.app$py.full_dispatch_request$70(C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bmhjzf\flask\flask\app.py:1645)
    at flask.app$py.call_function(C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bmhjzf\flask\flask\app.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:138)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:413)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:126)
    at flask.app$py.wsgi_app$85(C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bmhjzf\flask\flask\app.py:1996)
    at flask.app$py.call_function(C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bmhjzf\flask\flask\app.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:170)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:434)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:156)
    at flask.app$py.__call__$86(C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bmhjzf\flask\flask\app.py:2000)
    at flask.app$py.call_function(C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bmhjzf\flask\flask\app.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:170)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:434)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:156)
    at modjy.modjy$py.call_application$10(C:\Users\QTB0065\Apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\pampas\applications\pampas-be\WEB-INF\lib\jython.jar\Lib\modjy\modjy.py:109)
    at modjy.modjy$py.call_function(C:\Users\QTB0065\Apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\pampas\applications\pampas-be\WEB-INF\lib\jython.jar\Lib\modjy\modjy.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:188)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:446)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:171)
    at modjy.modjy$py.dispatch_to_application$9(C:\Users\QTB0065\Apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\pampas\applications\pampas-be\WEB-INF\lib\jython.jar\Lib\modjy\modjy.py:103)
    at modjy.modjy$py.call_function(C:\Users\QTB0065\Apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\pampas\applications\pampas-be\WEB-INF\lib\jython.jar\Lib\modjy\modjy.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:188)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:446)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:171)
    at modjy.modjy$py.service$7(C:\Users\QTB0065\Apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\pampas\applications\pampas-be\WEB-INF\lib\jython.jar\Lib\modjy\modjy.py:80)
    at modjy.modjy$py.call_function(C:\Users\QTB0065\Apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\pampas\applications\pampas-be\WEB-INF\lib\jython.jar\Lib\modjy\modjy.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:307)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:198)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:482)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:237)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:228)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:218)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:213)
    at org.python.core.PyObject._jcallexc(PyObject.java:3626)
    at org.python.proxies.modjy.modjy$modjy_servlet$0.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.xhaus.modjy.ModjyJServlet.service(ModjyJServlet.java:142)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The particular line of interest is:

**com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyException: INSTANCE_ALREADY_EXISTS: A BitsyGraph object with the same path has been registered with the MBeanServer. Creating multiple instances of BitsyGraph (without calling shutdown) will cause data corruption. Path C:\Users\QTB0065\AppData\Local\Temp\pampas\graph**

This apparently was caused because I would generate my graph, and then try to read it from another url ("servlet" [sic]) on the same server. If I already have a BitsyGraph object registered, and it exists, is there any way I can pass that instance around from one "servlet" to another?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the solution, and feel real dumb for not recognizing this. In order to make it work, I needed to make my graph object in the application context, and then I could use it everywhere.

```
with app.app_context():
    db_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'pampas', 'graph')
    with contextlib.suppress(OSError):
        os.makedirs(db_path)
    db_path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(db_path)
    flask.current_app.graph = com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyGraph(db_path)
```

Then I could use the same graph object in each routine I needed it, and the error doesn't exist.